# Saying a sentence without pronouncing the を particle

Tags: particle-を

I sometimes hear japanese natives say a sentence without using the を topic particle. For example, 「ご飯食べる」or 「お茶入れる」as opposed to 「ご飯**を**食べる」and 「お茶**を**入れる」

Is it a norm for japanese to neglect to を when speaking? Will the sentence be understandable 100% of the time?

Comment: @l'électeur I think it somewhat does, I'll take it as it is usual (if you are close to the person) to drop the を particle and still be 100% understandable. Cheers